# Could anyone introduce some books about Knot Theory and polynomial?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I've already learnt basic topology, and understood part of differental manifolds, the embedding, and part of algerbraic topology, the simplicit homology.

My boss advised me to finish a subject review about Knot Theory and polynomials as my graduation assignment, considering my knowledge. But I have no idea which book suits me. Could anyone help me? I'll appreciate a lot.

Comment: If you know basic algebraic topology (mainly the fundamental group, covering theory and homology), then "An introduction to knot theory" by Lickorish is a good starting point (at least it was mine :) ). Another good book where knot theory is done from the point of view of quantum topology is "Quantum invariants: a study of knots, 3-manifolds and their sets" by Ohtsuki.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I'll check them out.